# Can a program doing i/o on another drive cause writes in its home drive?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

Let's say I have a program `A` installed with windows on my drive `C:`.

I use `A` to do a lot of processing on a external drive `D:`. It reads from `D:`, processes the data, then writes the output back into `D:`.

Is it possible for windows to to cause writes by `A`'s processing into drive `C:`?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend mainly on the program A. If A is using some temporary file to hold intermediate results of the processing it is doing on drive `D:`'s data then there is a possibility that the temporary file is created in A's location and removed after its job is done. This depends mostly on the implementation of A. But yes given the scenario that you are talking about it is possible for A to write some information on its own drive during the process of processing the data.